# Modding the Witcher 2

Tags: mods, the-witcher-2

There seem to be some mods already floating around, the ones I saw were for enlarging the item tooltips and for increasing/eliminating the inventory limit. The mods themselves were just XML files that had to be copied into a certain folder.

From this I gather that one should be able to extract basic game parameters from the files present in the Witcher 2 installation. The quick availability of the first simple mods indicates that the game seems to be relatively mod-friendly.

How would one go about extracting the necessary XML files to start modding the Witcher 2?

Comment: ...I was in the middle of asking this same question. I suppose I'll stop now, since this is already here.

Answer (score 1):

- RED Tools has everything you need to extract these files: http://www.witchernexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=52
- A tutorial: http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Extracting_The_Witcher_2_files